# Cryptolicensing - in what way is the trial version limited?

Tags: .net, components, cryptolicensing

Lots of information on the [Cryptolicensing product home page](http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm) except for saying precisely how the trial version (of Cryptolicensing itself) is limited.

Nor is there any mention on the [download page](http://www.ssware.com/cryptolicensing/cryptolicensing_net.htm) itself.

Comment: I would suggest contacting their technical support.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... here's the answer from tech support:

> The CryptoLicensing Generator App will stop running after 30 days. Also, licenses generated with trial version (whether from the App or using API) will always expire after 30 days.